# List dates of files with sed

Tags: command-line, sed, ls

I am trying to extract the date modified/modified last week files and folders with `sed` but i am strugling.
Here's my opinion
`ls -l | sed '/codehere//g'`
but I have no idea how can this filtering be done, except with `awk`.

Output of my `ls -l` command:

```
vladimir@vladimir-K54L ~/Desktop $ ls -l
total 140
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir   516 Feb 27 19:33 4taOS.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir 63092 Feb 18 18:14 angela.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     0 Mar  4 00:23 _cmd.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir     5 Feb 27 19:26 dat6.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir   226 Feb 24 13:21 java.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir   299 Feb 27 19:27 lab1.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir   615 Mar  5 00:36 labperl2.plx
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir    18 Mar  3 12:44 naredbi.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir  1105 Mar  3 12:51 OSPRVKOL2015.plx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir   187 Feb 27 19:13 perl.plx
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir   257 Feb 23 21:44 primer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir   136 Feb 23 21:55 prva.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vladimir vladimir    44 Feb 23 21:56 treta.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir   137 Mar  4 23:17 vlade.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vladimir vladimir    67 Mar  3 12:44 vlez.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vladimir vladimir   110 Feb 23 21:52 vtora.sh
```

So I only need to print out the filenames, example `vtora.sh` depending on the dates modified (only for the last week).

Comment: What's your actual end goal here? Processing the output of `ls` is fragile (the default date format may change depending on the age of the file and the locale). There's probably a better solution using `find` or `stat`.

Comment: It's a task for my course. It says list only the dates of the files in the current directory using only `sed` and list all the files modified last week using `sed`. And I have no idea how this would work with sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you really don't want to be doing this. parsing the output of `ls` is very error prone and there are far better ways of achieving what you want (`find`, for example). However, I suspect your teacher wants to have you learn regular expressions and is just using this as an example. I certainly hope so, anyway.

In any case, this will work on the output you have shown on your question and for this week. It will fail next week and it will fail if your file names have spaces or other strangeness in their names. It will fail for any other dates than last week specifically. That said, it does work on your example:

```
$ ls -l | sed -En ' s/.*Feb *2[6-8].* (.*)/\1/p; s/.*Mar *[1-4].* (.*)/\1/p; '
4taOS.zip
_cmd.txt
dat1.txt
dat2.txt
dat3.txt
dat4.txt
dat5.txt
dat6.txt
lab1.sh
naredbi.txt
OSPRVKOL2015.plx
perl.plx
vlade.txt
vlez.txt
```

I am using `-E` which activates extended regular expressions (without this I'd need to escape the `(` and `)`) and `-n` which means "don't print unless I tell you to". Then, the substitution operator isl ooking for lines matching either `Feb 2` and any number between 6 and 8 (last weeks days in February) or `Mar` and any number from 1-4 (last week's dates in March). If those lines match, it replaces everything on the line with the last string of non space characters. That's what the parentheses do: they "capture" a pattern so it can be used on the right hand side of the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

[terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/889643/295286) provides a solution suitable for the professor's requirements. I would like to provide a solution that is proper. While it's certainly good and diligent to follow instructions in class, theory and practice often differ, and what professors teach/require in course sometimes isn't done professionally where you don't want to get yelled at by manager/customer.

The proper approach should be:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -mtime -7
```

The way this works is simple:

- `find` is a command that recursively traverses directory tree. In this case, we are using `GNU find` on Ubuntu.
- next argument is location - the parent directory which we want to traverse. In this case `.` can be left out and automatically assumed. On other OS `find` (if I recall correctly, BSD `find`) might require such option.
- `-maxdepth 1` limits us only to listing files in current directory.
- `-type f` will limit output to files only.
- `-mtime -7` will filter out files with modification time of `-7` days, i.e. a week.

Comment: I think definitely this should be the answer, because it's the most proper way to find stuff, with `find` command. Maybe our professor wanted just to take a good look at regular expressions. Thanks a lot :)